# Deleting a Template Type

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a generic class that looks something like this:

```
template <class T>
class Example
{
  private:
    T data;
  public:
    Example(): data(T())
    Example(T typeData): data(typeData) 
    ~Example()

    // ...
};
```

I'm a bit confused about how to implement a deconstructor for something like this. Specifically, since `T` is of any type, it could be memory allocated on the stack (which is always the case for `Example`'s created via the no-argument constructor) or on the heap.

For instance, if the client makes the type for `T` an `int*` and provides a pointer to dynamic memory, how do I know to call `delete` on `data` as opposed to if the client set the type to `int`?

Comment: Well you can be like the standard containers and not do that.  Standard container destructors will do nothing to the elements if the type is a pointer type.

Comment: Hint: use a CRTP policy type idiom based around `std::is_pointer<T>`. Have fun building it, then bin the whole thing since it's *really* hard to distinguish pointers to automatic variables from dynamic ones at the point of use.

Comment: Both valid points. I'm working on what I would consider to be more of an exercise, so I was ultimately just wondering if I was missing something, or if this was just a difficult thing to work around in general (which seems to be the case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest answer is: don't. Don't try to second-guess the user and do something they might not expect. Adopt the same policy as standard containers do: assume `T` cleans up after itself correctly.

If the client code is written correctly, it will use RAII classes (such as smart pointers) for automatic and correct management of memory and other resources. If it's not, you cannot hope to fix that in your provider code.

Make your class work with `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`, as well as any other custom RAII class, and let your clients do the management themselves. What if they want to store non-owning pointers, after all?

Comment: Fair enough -- that ambiguity of me managing the cleanup vs the client was really what I was concerned about.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Template Specialization.

```
template <class T>
class Example
{
  private:
    T data;
  public:
    Example()
        : data(T())
    {}

    Example(T typeData): data(typeData)
    {}
};

template <class T>
class Example<T*>
{
  private:
    T* data;
  public:
    Example() : data(nullptr){}
    Example(T* typeData): data(typeData) {}
    ~Example()
    {
        delete data;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Example<int> e;
    Example<int*> e2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool pattern. A lot easier to document behavior this way.

Comment: I would be careful about using this in production code. As others have said: it is difficult to tell whether a pointer points to `newed` storage or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could just not worry about it like the standard library does.  For example, if you create a vector of pointers you are responsible for deleting them before you let the vector go out of scope.  People can then decide if they even want it to be deleted at all (maybe it's temporary for sorting and something else owns the object).  They can also use smart pointers so that vector will destroy the object via the destructor for the smart pointer.

In this case, less is more.  You don't have to do anything complicated.  You don't have to maintain multiple versions of the template.  Finally, the user of your template has more control...and responsibility as well of course.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `std::unique_ptr` for `T` when you need `Example` to hold an owning pointer. If `T` is a raw pointer, then it's simply not owning and should not delete it.

If you need `Example` to initialize the pointer, specialize it for `std::unique_ptr`  and call `std::make_unique` in the default constructor.

```
template<typename T>
class Example<std::unique_ptr<T>> {
    Example() : data{std::make_unique<T>()} {}

    /* rest of the class */
};
```

If you do this, you should not specialize your class for `T*` to do a `new`, as you cannot initialise non-owning pointers. You should receive it in you constructor, and maybe disable the default constructor for raw pointers if you don't want it to be null.

```
template<typename T>
class Example<T*> {
    Example() = delete;
    Example(T* data_) : data{data_}

    /* data is not an owning pointer. No need for a destructor */

    /* rest of the class */
};
```

If you follow those rules, you should have no problem with memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Use memory release helper template classes that can be selected by type.
You does not need to make dublicate of your class with Template Specialization.
You can write only one class.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>   // primary template
struct Releaser
{
  template<typename V>
    void release( V v ) { }
};
template<>  // explicit specialization for T = std::true_type
struct Releaser<std::true_type>
{
  template<typename V>
    void release( V v ) { delete[] v; }
};

template <class T>
class Example
{
  private:
    T data;
  public:
    Example(): data(T()) {}
    Example(T typeData): data(typeData) {}
    typedef typename std::is_pointer<T>::value_type isptr_type;
    ~Example() {
      Releaser< isptr_type >::release( data );
    }
};
```

But need to know form of new called, so use delete or delete[].